# Parse Twitter authentication log out does not delete the token

Tags: authentication, twitter, parse-platform, logout

I am trying to let the users of my android app log in it via their Twitter account and ran into the following problem. I am using the Parse to store my data and users' information. When the user logs in and then logs out from the app via Twitter, there is a window with the message "authorize app to use your account", so the app is still associated with a particular twitter user. My problem is there is no window with email and password entries, when the user logs out via Twitter (ParseUser.logOut()). How can I unlink the app from the current user and present a new log in window.

Thank you!